# Dúvida funcionamento do código JS

Tags: javascript

tudo bom? 
Estou iniciando o aprendizado em JS e estou fazendo uma formula que não está dando certo. É bem simples, gostaria de clicar em um botão, esse botão não atualizar a página (fiz a função event.preventDefault()) e simplesmente aparecer um alert na tela. O código já possui algumas linhas devido ao calculo de IMC que criei, vou postar abaixo.

Já busquei a solução 500 vezes e não consigo enxergar o erro. Acredito que o JS não está conseguindo ler a função botao2 criada pois, ao inspecionar, a mesma aparece indefinida.

Vejam abaixo:

```
var pacientes = document.querySelectorAll(".paciente");

for (var i = 0; i <= pacientes.length; i++){

function totalImc (a, b){
    return a / (b * b);
}

var paciente = pacientes[i];


var peso = paciente.querySelector(".info-peso").textContent;
var altura = paciente.querySelector(".info-altura").textContent;
var valorImc = paciente.querySelector(".info-imc");

var pesoValido = true;
var alturaValida = true;

if (peso < 0 || peso > 300){
    pesoValido = false;
    valorImc.textContent = "Peso Inválido!";
    paciente.classList.add("erro");
}

if (altura < 0 || altura > 2.30){
    alturaValida = false;
    valorImc.textContent = "Peso Inválido!";
    paciente.classList.add("erro");
} 

if (alturaValida && pesoValido){
    var imc = totalImc(peso, altura);
    valorImc.textContent = imc.toFixed(0) +"%";
}

}

var botao2 = document.querySelector("#adicionar-paciente");
botao2.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Fui clicado!");
})
```

Código HTML (somente o body):

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="titulo">Aparecida Nutrição</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="container">
            <h2>Meus pacientes</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Peso(kg)</th>
                        <th>Altura(m)</th>
                        <th>Gordura Corporal(%)</th>
                        <th>IMC</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tabela-pacientes">
                    <tr class="paciente" id="primeiro_paciente" >
                        <td class="info-nome">Paulo</td>
                        <td class="info-peso">100</td>
                        <td class="info-altura">2.00</td>
                        <td class="info-gordura">10</td>
                        <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="paciente" >
                        <td class="info-nome">João</td>
                        <td class="info-peso">80</td>
                        <td class="info-altura">1.72</td>
                        <td class="info-gordura">40</td>
                        <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="paciente" >
                        <td class="info-nome">Erica</td>
                        <td class="info-peso">54</td>
                        <td class="info-altura">1.64</td>
                        <td class="info-gordura">14</td>
                        <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="paciente">
                        <td class="info-nome">Douglas</td>
                        <td class="info-peso">85</td>
                        <td class="info-altura">1.73</td>
                        <td class="info-gordura">24</td>
                        <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="paciente" >
                        <td class="info-nome">Tatiana</td>
                        <td class="info-peso">46</td>
                        <td class="info-altura">1.55</td>
                        <td class="info-gordura">19</td>
                        <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Formulário para adicionar pesos -->

<section class="container">
    <br/>
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Adicionar novo paciente</h2>
    <form id="form-adiciona">
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="digite o nome do seu paciente" class="campo">
        </div>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
            <input id="peso" name="peso" type="text" placeholder="digite o peso do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
        </div>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
            <input id="altura" name="altura" type="text" placeholder="digite a altura do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
        </div>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="gordura">% de Gordura:</label>
            <input id="gordura" name="gordura" type="text" placeholder="digite a porcentagem de gordura do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
        </div>

        <button id="adicionar-paciente" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
</section>

<!-- Importação do arquivo javascript -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/principal.js"></script>


</body>
```

Alguém poderia me dar um help, por favor?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basta deixar seu for dessa forma:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pacientes.length; i++)
```

O atributo length retorna o numero de itens dentro do seu array, porem a contagem dos índices começa no 0, de modo que a ultima execução do seu `for` não encontrava índice nenhum.

Se você der um `console.log(paciente)` antes de fazer essa alteração, vai perceber que o ultimo retorno é `undefined`, pois não mais índices no array pacientes para ele percorrer, dessa forma ele retornava um erro, de modo que sua variável botão2 nunca chegava a ser definida.

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel. Definitivamente um erro muito básico mas não estava enxergando isso.
Agradeço muito pela ajuda.